# Cloud Storage Transfer job fails with "Object: or"

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm having an issue transferring files from an S3 bucket to Google Cloud Storage.

The configuration of the job has an access key ID and secret key for a user which has AmazonS3FullAccess as policy. I verified access using aws-cli.

The path to the bucket is entered like `root-bucket/folder/`. There are no additional transfer options to the job.

The job runs for a while in the calculating state, and then fails with the error message

```
UNKNOWN: (showing 1 of 1 failures) >
Object: or
```

Is it possible to get a more verbose log of what failed with the job?

Comment: Sorry for the difficulty you are having. The issue is that the textbox housing the bucket name is intended to contain ONLY the bucket name. To specify only items below a certain folder, you would need to add that as an additional transfer option under "Transfer files with these prefixes". The correct config would look like this:

`Amazon S3 bucket: root-bucket
Transfer files with these prefixes: folder/`

We will improve the error messaging and client-side validation. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks rybosome, setting the folder as you mentioned worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rybosome metions, only the bucket name can be written in the `Amazon S3 bucket` field. When wanting to include sub-folders, write it in the more section, under include `Transfer files with these prefixes`.